# How to multiply two fields in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following query:

```
result = self.order_items.values('rate', 'rate_description')
    .annotate(quantity=Count('rate')).order_by('-quantity')
```

It gives me this:

```
[{'rate_description': u'CC only', 'rate': Decimal('121.00'), 'quantity': 2}]
```

How would I also get the quantity * rate? The resulting answer should give me:

```
[{'rate_description': u'CC only', 'rate': Decimal('121.00'), 'quantity': 2,
  'total': 242}]
```

Comment: Can you not just compute it in python? i.e. `obj["total"] = obj["rate"] * obj["quantity"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on the number of results, you could do it in python as @univerio noted in comment, or you could add [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra) query to put computation on the db

if your template is expecting a `total` attribute you could do it in your view by looping over results

```
for result in results:
   result['total'] = results['rate'] * result['quantity']
```